# ViewController from .xib file is loading in portrait mode and not in landscape mode in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I have created a ViewController that I am calling from my my Main ViewController.  I am able to successfully display the viewController, but my problem is that it is coming in Portrait mode, when in fact I have created it in Landscape mode.  The viewController I am loading is created in a separate .xib file which I call from my main application.  Here is the code I use to call it:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    
    NSLog(@"I was touched.");
    
    _nextView = [[NextLandscapeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextLandscapeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_nextView setDelegate:(id)self];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_nextView];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}
```

The thing that is confusing me is that I set the "Orientation" attribute for the view in the .xib file to Landscape in the "Attributes Inspector" in IB, yet it is still appearing in portrait mode. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the below methods in the NextLandscapeViewController

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

If the control doesn't reach these methods in View Controller, then you need to subclass the Navigation Controller.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  It looks like I'm going to have to subclass my Navigation Controller.  However, I am only working with a single view application, and the second view controller is coming from a .xib file.  How would I subclass the Navigation Controller in this circumstance?